# Updating the keys of a dictionary based on key and value of another dictionary

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a dictionary as

```
var dict1= { 'Pname1-type1-UOM1': 'D43',
  'Pname1-type2-UOM1': 'D59',
  'Pname1-type3-UOM2': 'D75',
  'Pname1-type4-UOM2': 'D91'
}
```

and another dictionary as

```
var dict2= { 'F43': 'Yearly',
  'F59': 'Monthly',
  'F75': 'Quarterly',
  'F91': 'Monthly'
}
```

What I want is a dict as

```
{ 'Pname1-type1-Yearly-UOM1': 'D43',
  'Pname1-type2-Monthly-UOM1': 'D59',
  'Pname1-type3-Quarterly-UOM2': 'D75',
  'Pname1-type4-Monthly-UOM2': 'D91'
}
```

What is similar between `dict1` and `dict2` is the first key value pair of `dict1` relates to first key value pair of `dict2` and the others also respectively.

Another similarity would be the value of `dict1` `D43` will have key in `dict2` as `F43`, so the D's are F's with same number following them

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, in your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var dict1 = {
  'Pname1-type1-UOM1': 'D43',
  'Pname1-type2-UOM1': 'D59',
  'Pname1-type3-UOM2': 'D75',
  'Pname1-type4-UOM2': 'D91'
};
var dict2 = {
  'F43': 'Yearly',
  'F59': 'Monthly',
  'F75': 'Quarterly',
  'F91': 'Monthly'
};
var obj = Object.entries(dict1).reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[v] = k, o), {});
var res = Object.entries(dict2).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
  var key = k.replace("F", "D");
  var temp = obj[key].split("-");
  temp.splice(2, 0, v);
  o[temp.join("-")] = key;
  return o;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

- When this script is run, the following object is obtained.

```json
{
  "Pname1-type1-Yearly-UOM1":"D43",
  "Pname1-type2-Monthly-UOM1":"D59",
  "Pname1-type3-Quarterly-UOM2":"D75",
  "Pname1-type4-Monthly-UOM2":"D91"
}
```

#### References:

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike- San, could you please help me explain the code snippet